# Are all Stochastic Processes "Automatically" Markov Chains?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I was reading these notes on Stochastic Process over here (http://faculty.washington.edu/yenchic/18A_stat516/Lec3_DTMC_p1.pdf). Over here, the following claim is stated:

[image]

The way this claim is written, it seems to suggest that there might be some Discrete Time Stochastic Process that **might not be** a Markov Chain if the stated condition is not satisfied (i.e. P(Xn = i conditional on Xn-1 = j....) only depends on P(Xn = i conditional on Xn-1 = j....) ). In this case, I believe that this stated condition is sometimes also called the "Markov Property".

However, I tried to think of counterexamples but I could not seem to think of a counterexample of a Discrete Time Stochastic Process that does satisfy the stated condition - suggesting that perhaps every Discrete Time Stochastic Process is "automatically" a Markov Chain.

I am aware that there are some Markov Chains in which the probability of the chain being in some state at a future time does not necessarily only depend on the current state - but rather, might depend on some finite history of states. For instance, a Markov Chain can be classified as a "Second Order Markov Chain" in which the probability of being in some state depends on the previous two states instead of only the previous state ([What is an example of a second-order markov chain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784975/what-is-an-example-of-a-second-order-markov-chain)).

- But in general, can all Discrete Time Stochastic Processes be considered as "some type of Markov Chains" (e.g. if not 1st order, perhaps 2nd order, 3rd order, etc.)?

Is this just a formality, or are there actually some Discrete Time Stochastic Processes that can fundamentally not be considered as Markov Chains?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a process that looks at the history arbitrarily far back. For example, you could have a coin that respects the gambler's fallacy: after a streak of $n$ times coming down one side, it has a $\frac1{n+1}$ probability of landing on that side again, and a $\frac{n}{n+1}$ probability of landing on the other side.

Then no $k^{\text{th}}$ order Markov chain can properly describe it. For any $k$, we can consider two situations: a streak of length $k$, and a streak of length $k+1$. These give different probabilities ($\frac1{k+1}$ and $\frac1{k+2}$) that the streak continues, but the $k^{\text{th}}$ order Markov chain can only treat them the same.

Comment: Thanks Misha! Can you please explain why there is no "k-th" order Markov Chain that can properly describe this situation? Thank you so much!

Comment: I've elaborated on the answer; does it help?

Comment: Thanks Misha! I think now I get it! Just one question: In the case of the Brownian Motion - can we say that the Brownian Motion is a Stochastic Process and is modelled using a Markov Chain?

Comment: Brownian motion is a continuous-time and continuous-space stochastic process, which changes the rules significantly, and I'm not super comfortable with the new rules. I am told that it's generally non-Markovian.

Comment: @ Misha: Hi Misha! I am trying to teach myself about Continuous Markov Chains - can you please take a look at this question if you arent too busy? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458150/properties-of-continuous-time-markov-chains Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Take $X_0$ to be a random (uniformly distributed) irrational number in $(0,1)$, and for $i>0$ let $X_i$ be the $i$th binary digit of $X_0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think you changed your answer - I liked the previous one better... is it possible to see the older one? Thank you so much!

Comment: The previous one was incorrect.

Comment: The point is that you need to carry “new random information” arbitrarily far forward.  The old answer carried random information forward from X_0 to X_i but it was not new, it could be deduced from X_{i-1}.  In this one the new information is really new.